# How to create a custom Xpath which uses contains method for two different strings

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I have two following XPath snippets and I want to merge them together to make one, can I do that?

```
xpath1 = /div/a[contains(@href,'location')]

xpath2 = /div/a[contains(@href,'city')]
```

Comment: maybe clarify a little.. are you trying to find more than one element?  There is an "or" operator in xpath... (and "and")

Answer (score 1):

The two [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- xpath1 = /div/a[contains(@href,'location')]
- xpath2 = /div/a[contains(@href,'city')]

can be merged using [java](/questions/tagged/java) notation as follows:

- Using `and`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(@href,'location') and contains(@href,'city')]"))
  ```
- Using `or`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(@href,'location') or contains(@href,'city')]"))
  ```

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks for the edit. Messed up the xpath with my sleepy eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest syntax is to use the union `|` operator. So in your case, you can use :

`/div/a[contains(@href,'location')]|/div/a[contains(@href,'city')]`

As a result you'll get elements which fulfill the first XPath expression + elements which fulfill the second XPath expression (+ elements which fulfill both expressions(not possible with your example since an `anchor` element supports only 1 `@href` attribute)).